# pwinty api callbaack url doesn't hit

Tags: asp.net-web-api, callback, httphandler, httpcontext

I am working with Pwinty api for photo printing. The callback url does not after every status changes against an order. Please help me to find solution.

Comment: If you want us to help you with your code, you need to show us your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that you can [edit] your question to include the missing information. See also our guide [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask a good question.